# String Mangling in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, string, obfuscation, name-mangling

I'm searching for a way to do string mangling in C/C++. The requirements for the software is that no plain text strings exist(No encryption needed, just mangling) and I'm attmping to figure out the path of least resistance for this requirement. Obfuscation and mangling of class names is covered through relatively easy to acquire tools but the string mangling seems to be a harder hurdle to jump.

I am comfortable with post processing of the software if that is the standard answer. Are their tools already written to do this or do I need to hack up my own scripts to munge strings?

Also I understand that mangling of the strings at rest is not really true security. I get that, and you likely get that but hey its a requirement that was placed on the software so I have to meet it.

Thanks! 
steph

Comment: To clarify, you want the strings to be obfuscated in the executable and then de-obfuscated at runtime?

Comment: See comment by @PeteBecker, or consider any simple substitution cipher, or XOR, or bit-shifting, or ........

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept of rot13 but can you give me some more information on the reccomended implementation? I can add a method that performs a rot13 and then wrapp all of my source code strings in a unrot(...) call. Then do I post process the binary to pre-rot them? Or is there a tool that I could add to my build process to pre-rot them prior to compilation?

Comment: I wonder who comes up first with a compile-time template metaprogramming scrambling so that one can enter clear text in the source code and have the compiler scramble it into the object file -- maybe this is a job for a raw templated user-defined literal ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple ROT13 Encrypter/Decrypter. No need to write a decryption function. Its called ROT13 because it simply rotates 13 characters back to its original state.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


  //encrypt or decrypt string
void ROT13_Encrypt_Decrypt_String(char str[]){

for( int i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++ ){
    if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'm'){
        str[i] += 13;
    }

    else if(str[i] > 'm' && str[i] <= 'z'){
        str[i] -= 13;
    }

    else if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'M'){
        str[i] += 13;
    }

    else if(str[i] > 'M' && str[i] <= 'Z'){
        str[i] -= 13;
    }

}
}


int main()
{
    char mystring [] = "Hello World!";
    cout << "Original string: " << mystring << endl;

    //encrypt   
    ROT13_Encrypt_Decrypt_String(mystring);   

    cout << "Encrypted string: " << mystring << endl;

    //decrypt  
    ROT13_Encrypt_Decrypt_String(mystring);

    cout << "Decrypted string: " << mystring << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Original string: Hello World!
Encrypted string: Uryyb Jbeyq!
Decrypted string: Hello World!
Press any key to continue
```

Comment: That requires him to run a program and "manually" mangle his strings and place the mangled strings in the source.

Comment: Not really. He could make a simple table "name = string"-style file, then run a program that creates a source file with the obfuscated strings to compile, and a header file that declares the strings.

Comment: @ChristianStieber can you elaborate on the program to create this obfuscated strings prio to compile time. Thats the part I'm struggling with. I understand adding a ROT method to decrypt/encrypt at runtime but I need something that ROT's them prior to buildling as at rest the strings are non-readable.

Comment: @WithoutMeItJustAweso You just have `strings.h` file containing all of your raw strings (say in the form `#define key="original"`), and a script or program that takes each line and extracts the value, `ROT13`s it, and prints `#define key="rot13"` to another file. Then `#include` the second file in your project, and as a pre-build step, run the script.

Comment: That script or program you speak of is what I'm in search for. I feel like it shouldn't be that uncommong and I'm trying not to reinvent the wheel if I dont have to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with ASCII text, simply set the 7th bit on each character to de-plain-text it, then unset it to turn it into plain-text.